# Virtual topics work when using ActiveMQ 5.x's connection factory, but not Artemis' connection factory

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, activemq-artemis

I am in the process of migrating existing code from working with ActiveMQ 5.x  to work with Artemis. When using `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory`, my virtual topic consumers queues have messages that are sent to the virtual topic enqueued to them. When using `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory`, they do not.

The connection pool configuration that works for the virtual topics using ActiveMQ 5.x's connection factory is:

```xml
<bean id="jmsFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
            <property name="brokerURL" value="failover:${activemq.broker}" />
            <property name="userName"  value="${activemq.credentials.username}"/>
            <property name="password"  value="${activemq.credentials.password}"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="maxConnections"                    value="${activemq.connectionPool.size}" />
    <property name="maximumActiveSessionPerConnection" value="${activemq.connectionPool.sessionsPerConnection}" />
</bean>
```

The connection pool configuration that **does not** work for virtual topics using Artemis' connection factory is:

```xml
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
            <constructor-arg name="url"      value="${activemq.broker}"/>
            <constructor-arg name="user"     value="${activemq.credentials.username}"/>
            <constructor-arg name="password" value="${activemq.credentials.password}"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="maxConnections"                    value="${activemq.connectionPool.size}" />
    <property name="maximumActiveSessionPerConnection" value="${activemq.connectionPool.sessionsPerConnection}" />
</bean>
```

For the virtual topic, my consumers are Camel routes, and producers are instances of Spring's `JmsTemplate` class. The producers are configured to produce to topics in the pattern `VirtualTopic.Foo`, and the consumers are configured to consume from Camel endpoints in the pattern `jms:queue:VirtualTopic.Foo::Consumer.MyApplication.VirtualTopic.Foo`.
The `jms` Camel component is configured with the `jmsFactory` bean from above, as are the `JmsTemplate` instances:

```xml
<bean id="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory"  ref="jmsFactory"/>
    <property name="deliveryPersistent" value="${activemq.delivery.persistent}"/>
</bean>
```

Ideally, I would be able to use Artemis' `ActiveMQConnectionFactory`. What is causing messages sent to virtual topics to not get dispatched to the consumers queues when using it?

Comment: Why not just continue using `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory` since it works? What's the goal of switching to `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory`?

Comment: @JustinBertram Along with the upgrade, I had to transition from using the broker statistics plugin to performing operations against `activemq.management` queue, which throws a validation error if  the connections performing the operations were not created using Artemis' connection factory. For that reason, I currently have connection pools using both connection factories configured and injected where required, but I would like to simplify the configuration by only having a single connection pool.

Comment: What "validation error" were you getting when using `activemq.management` from an OpenWire connection? I would expect that to work.

Comment: @JustinBertram The error comes when using `JMSManagementHelper.putOperationInvocation` inside of Spring's `JmsTemplate.sendAndReceive`: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot send a foreign message as a management message org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMessage` at `org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.jms.management.JMSManagementHelper.getCoreMessage(JMSManagementHelper.java:33) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]`

Comment: OK. That makes sense. You're using a helper class (i.e. `JMSManagementHelper`) that is designed for a specific message implementation. To be clear, the helper class is not strictly necessary. It just makes formatting the management messages a bit easier. There's nothing stopping you from putting the proper headers into the message manually.

Comment: Have you tried using the JMS component in your Camel endpoint? [Camel's documentation for the ActiveMQ component](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.7.x/activemq-component.html) states, "Users of Apache ActiveMQ Artemis should use the JMS component."

Comment: Good to know! I formed the `activemq.management` message manually and received the response; I'll work on getting the response JSON parsed out later. I'll also try using `jms` instead of `activemq` and report on the results when I can. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Changing my camel component from `activemq` to `jms` was a welcomed change, but it did not solve the issue; my virtual topic consumer queues still only get messages enqueued when using the ActiveMQ 5.x connection factory to create the consumer queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may or may not have had anything to do with the JMS driver being used. It seems to have been an issue with how and when the virtual topics and their consumers were created. How I came to this realization is detailed below, but, in short, make sure that the virtual topic is created before creating consumers on it.

---

I noticed that one of my virtual topics, `VirtualTopic.Fig` was working, but none of my other virtual topics were. All of the consumer queues for the virtual topics were created using the fully qualified queue name, as described in the [Artemis documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/migration-documentation/VirtualTopics.html) (subscribing to the queue `VirtualTopic.Fig::Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.Fig` instead of to `Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.Fig`). I ran the `listAddresses` management command and saw this output for the virtual topics:

```
name                        size    consumers      anycast    multicast 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
VirtualTopic.Apple             -            1            Y            -
VirtualTopic.Banana            -            1            Y            -
VirtualTopic.Cantaloupe        -            1            Y            -
VirtualTopic.DragonFruit       -            1            Y            -
VirtualTopic.ElderBerry        -            1            Y            -
VirtualTopic.Fig               -            1            Y            Y
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Using the `updateAddress` command (`updateAddress VirtualTopic.DragonFruit ANYCAST,MULTICAST`), I updated `VirtualTopic.DragonFruit` to have multicast routing, restarted my consumers, and most of them began to receive messages. Assuming that the remaining consumers did not work because they were created before the topic was created and were bound to an anycast version of the address, for each address, I:

1. Shut down all of my applications that produced or consumed from the virtual topics.
2. Used the `destroyQueue` command (`destroyQueue Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.DragonFruit true true`) to destroy the consumer queue.
3. Used the `deleteAddress` command (`deleteAddress VirtualTopic.DragonFruit`) to delete the topic.
4. Used the `createAddress` command (`createAddress VirtualTopic.DragonFruit MULTICAST`) to create the topic as a multicast address.
5. Started all of the applications up again.

After manually creating the virtual topics, everything started working. The new output of the `listAddresses` command was:

```
name                        size    consumers      anycast    multicast 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
VirtualTopic.Apple             -            1            -            Y
VirtualTopic.Banana            -            1            -            Y
VirtualTopic.Cantaloupe        -            1            -            Y
VirtualTopic.DragonFruit       -            1            -            Y
VirtualTopic.ElderBerry        -            1            -            Y
VirtualTopic.Fig               -            1            -            Y
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And the output of the `listQueues` command showed that the consumers were now receiving messages:

```
name                                   size    consumers     enqueued     dequeued 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.Apple             0            1           88           88
Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.Banana            0            1            4            4
Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.Cantaloupe        0            1           12           12
Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.DragonFruit       0            1           74           74
Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.ElderBerry        0            1         1776         1776
Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.Fig               0            1           75           75
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```